# Applying filters on filtered data with pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filter, filtering

I have a pandas data frame and I want to apply filters after filters in a way that I have not found out yet. To give more context, column A is a placeholder for different IPs, while column B is a placeholder for firm ID. I want the first filter to look at how many times an IP is present. If the IP is present only once or if the IP is present more than 3 times, the rows should be excluded. This part, I managed to solve. The problem is that now, I want that each IP that remains in the database to have at least 2 distinct firms accessed. The code is posted below and after there will be output and expected output.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['001', '001', '002', '003', '003', '003', '003', '004', '004'],
                   'B': ['firm_a', 'firm_a', 'firm_b', 'firm_a', 'firm_c', 'firm_d', 'firm_a', 'firm_a', 'firm_b']},
                  index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

df = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
df = df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) < 4)

print(df)
```

Current output:

```
     A       B
0  001  firm_a
1  001  firm_a
7  004  firm_a
8  004  firm_b
```

Now, I want to implement the second filter, that checks if an IP accessed at least 2 different firms. In the example provided, the expected output would be the following:

```
     A       B
7  004  firm_a
8  004  firm_b
```

As you can see, IP 001 was removed because it passed the first filter (accessed 2 or more firms), but it accessed the same firm and it was eliminated. I don't know how to implement the second part. I tried looking around and while there are a lot of pandas tutorials out there about filtering, I didn't find something that would fit my problem. While yes, I can do it in python by taking each IP apart and get a list of the accessed firms, eliminate duplicates and see if the length of the list is higher than 1, this is very computationally expensive. I have close to 1 billion rows and it would take too much time to do this. Is there any smart way you can set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `transform` with `nunique`:

```
res = df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('nunique') >= 2]

print(res)

   A       B
7  4  firm_a
8  4  firm_b
```